# Having issue for rendering user control after async postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have script manager in master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptLocalization ="true" EnableScriptGlobalization ="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" >
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

MyPage.aspx (Placed in contentplaceholder of master page)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefresh" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

MyPage.aspx script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(myfun, 20000);
    });

    function myfun() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>');
                    btn.click();
    }
```

On the place holder I'm putting dynamically created table containing user controls.
On the page load, I can see the user controls on the page. But when Async postback is called after 20 seconds, I don't see the user controls. With firebug, I see that user controls are there. But they do not get rendered; even though I'm creating them again on async postback. They appears to be empty. Help.

Comment: Can you show me page_load event code?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
 GetData(); // get data from database
 LoadUserControls(); // Create dynamic table containing user controls
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You need to create controls on every page postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
      { 
           GetData(); // get data from database 
      } 
           LoadUserControls(); // Create dynamic table containing user controls 

}
```

I think you should read this.  [Loading UserControl Dynamically in UpdatePanel](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/11/Loading-UserControl-Dynamically-in-UpdatePanel.aspx)

Comment: Link looks promising though. I'll give a try.